# Python Recreating Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below:

```
df =
    yy  mm  col1  col2
   2020   7  0.22  10
   2020   7  0.50  30
   2020   7  0.60  40
   2020   7  0.50  70
   2020   7  0.60  90
```

And I want to divide the dataframe into 3 parts and transpose it such that it will resut as:

```
     yy    mm   col1    col2  col1   col2   col1   col2
     2020   7   0.22     10   0.60   40    0.60    90
     2020   7   0.50     30   0.50   70     NaN    NaN
```

What I did now so far is:

```
a = np.array_split(df,3)

a =
[    yy  mm  col1  col2
   2020   7  0.22  10
   2020   7  0.50  30,
     yy  mm  col1  col2
   2020   7  0.60  40,
   2020   7  0.50  70
     yy  mm  col1  col2
   2020   7  0.60  90]
```

And later I convert each element of list in a into dataframe: a0 = a[0], a1 = a[1] and a2=a[2] and later do pandas.concat([a0,a1,a2], axis = 1, keys = ['yy','mm']).
However, my solution is troublesome if I have much larger dataframe df and I  split it into many parts (instead of just 3).
Thank you.

Comment: I think your code is correct, but what do you find tricky about it?

Comment: I actually look for a more efficient way of doing it in case my dataframe is much larger and I need to divide it into many parts (instead just of 3 parts).

Comment: instead of saving them into individual variables, you can directly concat them: `a = np.array_split(df,3)` 
 then `pd.concat([i.reset_index() for i in a],axis=1)`

Comment: How about adding a new column so that it can be transformed by pivoting? `df['flg']=[1,1,2,2,3,3,...]' `how about updating the column names after that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'yy':[2020]*5,'mm':[7]*5,'col1':[0.22,0.5,0.6,0.5,0.6],'col2':[10,30,40,70,90]})


length=2
lis=[]
i=0


while i<(len(df)/length)+length:
    lis.append(df.iloc[i:i+length,:].reset_index(drop=True))
    i+=length

final=pd.concat(lis,axis=1)
```

Only drawback is the first two columns are repeated too.
need to find a way to work around it.

or you can:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'yy':[2020]*5,'mm':[7]*5,'col1':[0.22,0.5,0.6,0.5,0.6],'col2':[10,30,40,70,90]})

a=np.array_split(df,len(df)/length)
pd.concat([i.reset_index(drop=True) for i in a],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

May have to use couple of steps

```
df1=df.set_index([df.index % 2, df.index // 2]).unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1,ascending=True)#Split dataframe on every 2nd row
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(1)#drop multi level index
m=df1.loc[:,['mm','yy']]#Isolate columns with yy, mm
s=m.loc[:,~m.columns.duplicated()]#drop duplicates in isolated above
t=df1.filter(regex='^col', axis=1)#filter rows with col

res=pd.concat([s,t], axis=1)#Concat into new frame res



   mm    yy  col1  col2  col1  col2     col1  col2
0  7.0  2020.0  0.22  10.0   0.6  40.0   0.6  90.0
1  7.0  2020.0  0.50  30.0   0.5  70.0   NaN   NaN
```